# Include relational data in a rest response

Tags: yii2

What is the Yii-way to include relational data in a rest response?

Scenario: I have a model with customers and a model with customer addresses, and I want `my-application.com/customers` to return something along the lines of:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Customer #1",
    "org_no": "2342342",
    "created_at": "2017-04-28 00:00:00",
    "created_by": 1,
    "updated_at": "2017-04-28 00:00:00",
    "updated_by": 1,
    "customer_since": "2016-10-10 00:00:00",
    "next_follow_up": "2017-04-29 00:00:00",
    "email_invoice": 1,
    "invoice_email": "invoice@customer.com",
    "invoice_address": 1
    "addresses": [
        {
            "street": "teststreet 1",
            "postal": 12345
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a relation in the model `Customer` that gets you all customer addresses, namely `getAdresses`, you should implement there the `extraFields()` method as:

```
public function extraFields() {
        return [
            'addresses' => 'addresses',
        ];
    }
```

Then, to include that relational data, you'll call your API like this:

```
application.com/customers?expand=addresses
```